# mysql trigger error with 2 conditions

Tags: mysql, triggers, conditional-statements

I want to add an after insert trigger which will do the following.

The first IF condition works normally, but when it comes to the second everything stops.

Any ideas?

```
USE `Syslog`;
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER `SystemEventsR_AINS` AFTER INSERT ON SystemEventsR FOR EACH ROW

IF 
(exists
(select syslogtag from SystemEventsRcounter where syslogtag=
new.syslogtag) 

AND

(select simpledate from SystemEventsRcounter
where syslogtag=new.syslogtag)=new.simpledate) 

THEN
UPDATE SystemEventsRcounter 
SET records=records+1
WHERE SystemEventsRcounter.syslogtag=new.syslogtag;

ELSE INSERT SystemEventsRcounter (simpledate, syslogtag, records) values (new.simpledate,new.syslogtag,1);
END IF
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATED**:

What you need is [`INSERT INTO ... ON DUPLICATE KEY`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html).

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER `SystemEventsR_AINS` 
AFTER INSERT ON SystemEventsR 
FOR EACH ROW
    INSERT INTO SystemEventsRcounter (simpledate, syslogtag, records) 
    VALUES (NEW.simpledate, NEW.syslogtag, 1)
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE records = records + 1;
```

In order for it to work you need to create a unique composite index on (simpledate, syslogtag)

```sql
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX idx_u_simpledate_syslogtag
ON SystemEventsRcounter (simpledate, syslogtag);
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a593f0/1)** demo.

If you wanted it your way then it might look like

```sql
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `SystemEventsR_AINS` 
AFTER INSERT ON SystemEventsR 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF ( 
          SELECT COUNT(*) simpledate 
            FROM SystemEventsRcounter 
           WHERE syslogtag  = NEW.syslogtag
             AND simpledate = NEW.simpledate
       ) > 0 THEN
        UPDATE SystemEventsRcounter 
           SET records = records + 1
        WHERE SystemEventsRcounter.syslogtag = NEW.syslogtag;
    ELSE 
        INSERT INTO SystemEventsRcounter (simpledate, syslogtag, records) 
        VALUES (NEW.simpledate, NEW.syslogtag, 1);
    END IF;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b75062/1)** demo.

Comment: it still does not work though..i'm trying to find out if its a logical error rather than a syntax error, thank you anyway

Comment: I'm not getting any error, but the trigger stops.

When i omit the second condition (the simpledate thing) then everything rolls fine.

Comment: it's like something is going on with the AND which connects the two conditions. Is there any case that MySQL does not understand AND inside an IF statement?

Comment: Sometimes when you focus so much on a problem, you lose the big picture. The actual problem was that I've created a unique key for syslogtag, so new inserts with the same syslogtag but with different simpledate could not be done.

But anyway, the solution of "insert on duplicate key" is far more efficient.

Thank you again, I really appreciate it.